# twitter bootstrap table alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and trying to get two tables to align. I'm starting to think I'm going about it the wrong way. I have two tables one with 3 columns and one with 2 columns. I've set the 3 column table to span6, span2,span4. I've set the 2 column table to span6 and span6. They don't seem to always align in the middle depending on page width. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PSBtr/

```
<html>
<head><link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

    <body>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="span6">fdsafdfdf f dfdafs sd</th>
        <th class="span2">tesaaat</th>
        <th class="span4">ffdsfsd d</th>                     
    </tr>
</thead>

</table>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="span6" >fdfdf  fds f </th>
    <th class="span6">test</th>
</tr>
</thead>

</table>

</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Ultimately I'm trying to design a somewhat fluid layout that also has tables that will expand but have a minimum size. Any additional suggestions on which layout (from bootstrap) could accomplish this would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below code will accomplish what you are trying to achieve:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr class="span12">
        <th class="span6">fdsafdfdf f dfdafs sd</th>
        <th class="span2">tesaaat</th>
        <th class="span4">ffdsfsd d</th>  
    </tr>
</thead>

</table>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr class="span12">
    <th class="span6">fdfdf  fds f </th>
    <th class="span6">test</th>
</tr>
</thead>

</table>
```

For the later part of your question it would be difficult to say as it would depend on exact requierments but yes, you may try a Single column [Fluid layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts)..In case users would be browsing through compact screen sizes then you have to consider a [Responsive design](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)..

Comment: definitely better, do you know why the two versions of tables here aren't identical? http://jsfiddle.net/PSBtr/

Comment: i am not sure right now why they are not identical..you may check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUAHB/), if it helps..